# How to get access_tokens using Rails and Strava API

Tags: ruby, api, oauth

Has anyone ever used the Strava API? I'm attempting to build my first app where I need to access an API using access_tokens for each user.

I've read http://strava.github.io/api/v3/oauth/ and understand the protocol however I'm stuck at one stage and not sure what to do.

In my Rails app I've just created a controller to help me get my head round this with a index and exchange action.

In the index view I've put a link to strava_domain/oauth/authorize along with the correct attributes. It's calling back to my /exchange action with the state and code. The problem is I don't know how to make a post call to strava_domain/oauth/token with the correct attributes.

Is there a gem to handle oauth2 protocols like this or do people normally write these protocols in manually using Httparty (I dont understand how to use it too well).

Also I'm assuming after this stage I will be able to grab the access token from the response and add it to a user object (as a new column).

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Johnny.

(I'm using Ruby 2.1.2 and Rails 4)

Comment: Oauth is a pretty well-established thing - I'd use the `oauth2` gem, or even the [`strava-api`](https://github.com/stevenchanin/strava-api) gem!

Comment: Hi Sam thanks for your response. I think the `strava-api` gem is rather outdated. A more recent ruby gem for Strava is [here](https://github.com/jaredholdcroft/strava-api-v3) however it doesn't cover the authentication side of things.

Comment: OK! Maybe you can use the two in conjunction then - but the `oauth2` gem might be a good place to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Slava](https://slava.playplay.io) code using [strava-api-v3](https://github.com/jaredholdcroft/strava-api-v3).

```
response = Strava::Api::V3::Auth.retrieve_access(
 ENV['STRAVA_CLIENT_ID'], 
 ENV['STRAVA_CLIENT_SECRET'], 
 request['code']
)
raise "Strava returned #{response.code}: #{response.body}" unless response.success?
# response['token_type'] is "Bearer"
# response['access_token'] is the user token.
```

More working code [here](https://github.com/dblock/slack-strava/blob/master/slack-strava/models/user.rb).